# jquery replace title with input value

Tags: jquery, input, title, attr

How can I replace **all input titles value** in a form with input or textarea values using Jquery and 'each' ?

```
<form id="id001" action="" method="post">
    <fieldset id="F001">
    <legend>F001 : Consulter mes informations professionnelles</legend>
    <div id="msg"></div>
    <label for="EMPLOYEE_NUMBER">
        Matricule de l'agent:
    </label>
    <input name="EMPLOYEE_NUMBER" type="text" id="EMPLOYEE_NUMBER" value="ID999" readonly="readonly" />
    <br /> 
    <label for="LAST_NAME">
        Nom:
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="LAST_NAME" id="LAST_NAME" value="Test" title="" />
    <br /> 
    <label for="FIRST_NAME">
        Prénom:
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="FIRST_NAME" id="FIRST_NAME" value="Jack" title="" />
    <br /> 
    <br class="clear" />
    <label>
        &nbsp;
    </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" />
        <input name="WF" type="hidden" id="WF" value="WF2" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Thanks for your help...

Chris

Comment: You shouldn't use all-caps in any attribute value, or tags for that matter. Also, you need to be clearer on what you mean by `replace all input titles value`. Do you want this to happen when the submit button is clicked, or when the input's value changes?

Comment: you shouldn't just place an order to have some code done for you. Tell us what you have tried show some example code.  What errors are you getting.  Why do you think you are getting them.  If you want something just... done for you, I recommend a freelance site

Comment: When the page load (sorry for missing that)

Comment: @austinbv : OK next time I will put the code I tried to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$("input, textarea").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("title", this.value);
});
```